# Go back to current directory from any directory in mac os

Tags: linux, macos, operating-system

I have a terminal open from one of my projects. Let's say at that time I was in `/Users/test_user/Desktop/Project/test_project`.

Now in that same terminal, I changed the directory to home(~). Now I wanted to go back to the directory from which I opened the terminal initially. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: This looks like what you need -> https://dev.to/mrahmadawais/devtip-go-back-to-the-previous-directory-33aa

Comment: You can go back to the previous directory with `cd -`. If you want to go to a particular directory, you could set a variable (`export THE_DIR=$(pwd)`) and later `cd "$THE_DIR"`. Maybe if you put the `export ...` in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.zshrc` or whatever startup file your shell uses, it gets set when you open the terminal. That said, this seems more a question about shell commands, but not about programming, so it's IMHO off-topic here. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cd -`  to go back to your previous directory which is inside `OLDPWD` environment variable.

If you want to go, to another directory (which is not the previous directory you are in), there are multiple ways to do it. One way is, you can see the directory stack by the command `dirs -v`. Sample output wil be like this:

```
0   ~/workspace/stack/c
1   ~/Downloads
2   ~
```

Then you can use `cd ~$INDEX`, here the `INDEX` being the number shown in the `dirs -v` output. So `cd ~1` will cd into `~/Downloads` in the above example.

Another interesting commands to take a look at it are [pushd](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pushd/) and [popd](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/popd/).

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful :)

Comment: @jenildesai25 that’s great to hear :) you can accept the answer :)